# Derivation of $\operatorname{Var}(Y|X)= E(Y^2|X)-(E(Y|X))^2$ & $\operatorname{Var}(Y) = E(\operatorname{Var}(Y|X))+\operatorname{Var}(E(Y|X))$

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

Starting with $\operatorname{Var}(Y|X) = E((Y-E(Y|X))^2|X)$

> How were the two below forms of $\operatorname{Var}$ derived from the above?

$$1)\quad \dots \quad \operatorname{Var}(Y|X)= E(Y^2|X)-(E(Y|X))^2$$

$$\quad\quad\,2) \quad \dots \quad \operatorname{Var}(Y) = E(\operatorname{Var}(Y|X))+\operatorname{Var}(E(Y|X))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all see that:
$$
\textrm{Var}\left(Y|X\right)= \mathbb E\left((Y-\mathbb E(Y|X))^2\big|X\right)=\\
\mathbb E\left(Y^2-2Y\mathbb E(Y|X)+(\mathbb E(Y|X))^2\big|X\right)=\\
\mathbb E\left(Y^2\big|X\right)- (\mathbb E(Y|X))^2
$$
where we used the following:
$$
\mathbb E\left(Y\mathbb E(Y|X)\big|X\right)=\mathbb E(Y\big|X)\mathbb E\left(Y\big|X\right).
$$
As for the second equality; First see that:
$$
\mathbb E(\textrm{Var}\left(Y|X\right))=\mathbb E(\mathbb E\left(Y^2\big|X\right)- (\mathbb E(Y|X))^2)=\\
\mathbb E(Y^2)-E\left((\mathbb E(Y|X))^2\right).
$$
For the second term we have:
$$
\textrm{Var}\left(\mathbb E(Y|X)\right)=\mathbb E\left((\mathbb E(Y|X))^2\right)-\left(\mathbb E(\mathbb E(Y|X))\right)^2=\mathbb E\left((\mathbb E(Y|X))^2\right) -(\mathbb E(Y))^2.
$$
Combining these two will give you the proof of second result.

Comment: Which one was that a hint for sorry? First one?

Comment: Does $E(Y^2|X) = E(Y|X)^2$?

Comment: Does $E(E(Y|X))=E(Y)$?

Comment: Well, I updated the answer. Your last statement is correct and it is usually called tower property of conditional expectation. However the previous one is incorrect.

Comment: Very nice answer, still reading it, I will tell you if I have an issues!